# How to prompt the "open with" menu after download a zip file

Tags: java, android

In my app I download .zip files. Is there a way when those files are downloaded, have a button/notification when clicked prompt the "open with" menu with third party compatible apps?

How to do that without knowing which zip handling apps are installed in the user phone?

Also, how to apply to apk files , to prompt app install ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(path);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/zip");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try. By the way, there when files are .apk, how to prompt the app install ?

Comment: remove: intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/zip");

Answer (score 0):

If you add a button to open the file, it will take care of all of this automatically.